# Странное поведение log4j: <context-param> мешает log4j

Tags: tomcat, log4j

В Tomcat'е лежат два приложения: *apps* и *zaz*. В папке *Tomcat\lib* лежит файл *log4j.properties* - общий для обоих приложений. Для первого приложении путь для вывода логов настроен следующим образом (в файле *log4j.properties*):

```
log4j.appender.apps.File=/usr/local/tomcat/logs/apps/apps.log
```

и для второго аналогично:

```
log4j.appender.zaz.File=/usr/local/tomcat/logs/zaz/zaz.log
```

И в чём заключается странность: в папке *apps* есть файл *apps\Web-inf\classes\com\comp\cust.properties*, а в файле *apps\Web-inf\web.xml*
есть следующие строки:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>propsFile</param-name>
    <param-value>com\comp\cust.properties</param-value> 
</context-param>
```

При этом, если эти строки закомментированы, то в файл */usr/local/tomcat/logs/zaz/zaz.log* логи пишутся, а если не закомментированы, то этот файл создаётся, но логи в него не пишутся. Причём это даже происходит даже тогда, когда файл cust.properties абсолютно пустой!

**UPD**

При этом, если перенести всё содержимое файла *log4j.properties* в файл *cust.properties*, логи в файл */usr/local/tomcat/logs/zaz/zaz.log* пишутся.

Каким образом эта настройка (`propsFile`), влияет на работу log4j?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте удалить $CATALINA_BASE/conf/logging.properties, чтобы предотвратить создание с нулевым размером логов логером java.util.logging.
Данный шаг является одной из рекомендаций в главе "Using Log4j" мануала к Tomcat [(ref)](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html)

В целом, в Java большая проблема с расплодившимися логерами [(ref)](https://habrahabr.ru/post/113145/), поэтому в Ваших приложениях и настройках Tomcat возможны конфликты.

Как ещё один вариант убедитесь, что на диске есть место на момент логирования.

Comment: $CATALINA_BASE/conf/logging.properties уже удалён и место на диске точно есть

Comment: Попробуйте данный код в ваших приложениях чтобы отследить куда пишется лог:    Enumeration e = Logger.getRootLogger().getAllAppenders();
    while ( e.hasMoreElements() ){
      Appender app = (Appender)e.nextElement();
     if ( app instanceof FileAppender ){
    System.out.println("File: " + ((FileAppender)app).getFile());
  }
}

Comment: Странно, вывод как-то не похож на реальность: вывело только один аппендер - "File: D:\Tomcat/logs/catalina".

Comment: И да, в log4j.properties root-appender только один, log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CATALINA, но кроме этого много ещё аппендеров-потомков

Comment: Стоит показать log4j.properties, может кто-нибудь зацепится взглядом. Нет ли иерархии между аппендерами apps и zaz? А вообще, баги с Log4j не нонсенс, как я представляю, попробуйте взглянуть в сторону использования в Ваших приложениях обёртки в лице Slf4j.

Comment: Так ведь проблема, кажется, не в log4j.properties, а в cust.properties... Без этого файла, когда соответствующая опция <context-param> закомментирована, всё работает нормально. И меня интересует, почему так происходит.

Comment: На мой взгляд, <context-param> в web.xml одного приложения (apps) , не может влиять на другое (zaz). Единственную связь между ними из предоставленых Вами данных я вижу в настройках логера. Например подчинение aппендера zaz к аппендеру apps из-за чего при смене настроек логирования apps (посредством <context-param>) получаем данный результат. Другое мнение мне было бы тоже интересно услышать.

Comment: log4j.properties достаточно объёмный, но подчинение аппендера zaz аппендеру apps я отключила настройкой: `log4j.additivity.com.comp.zaz=false`